# Java Lexical Analyzer

Tags: java, lexical-analysis

i'm creating a lexical analyzer. in my code i can output the symbols, but when it comes to letters and numbers i cant design what will be my code in that..

please help me in my project.. thanks

```
package lab7;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Lab7 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
                String word;
        char[] wordArray;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        wordArray = word.toCharArray();

        for(int x = 0; x < wordArray.length; x++) {

            if(wordArray[x] == '+') {
                System.out.print("ADD ");
            }
            else if(wordArray[x] == '-') {
                System.out.print("SUBTRACT ");
            }
            else if(wordArray[x] == '*') {
                System.out.print("MULTIPLY ");
            }
            else if(wordArray[x] == '/') {
                System.out.print("DIVIDE ");
            }
            else if(wordArray[x] == '(') {
                System.out.print("MATH ");
            }
            else if(wordArray[x] == ')') {
                System.out.print("MATH ");
            }
            else if(wordArray[x] == '=') {
                System.out.print("ASSIGN ");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is quite broad as is. Could you be more specific? What in particular are you having trouble with?

Comment: Not a good type of question? You want us to do your homew... i mean project?

Comment: Please DO NOT compare String in Java with ==! It does not work always, keep that in mind! Secondly to go more advanced take a look at the Antlr Project: http://www.antlr.org/

Comment: @Zarathustra there are `char`s not `String`s

Comment: @MaxVasileusky you are right, my fault.

Comment: @arshajii i am having trouble with letters and numbers sir. because i need to show that the output when letters are inputted is equivalent to ID

Comment: @Leo i'm not saying to give the answer to me. i just need help

Answer (score 1):

`Character` methods `Character.isLetter` and `Character.isDigit` may help you here.

However you can't write real lexical analyzer by only scanning string letter by letter. Lexical analyzer produces multi-character tokens and usually implemented as a state machine, which is defined by regular expressions.

Automatic splitting isn't useful here. For example, if you'll split input string by whitespaces, `12+34` will be a single token. So your should define some rules, for example, read digits, while there are digits, and so on.. This leads to the idea of ​​a finite automaton (or a state machine).

Comment: yes sir. you are right. but what if i tokenize the inputted string so that i can read words not only letters.

Comment: @Joseph I've seen `import java.util.StringTokenizer;` in your code :) I didn't use it before, but it seems like this class may be helpful for you. Take a look at examples of its usage.